# What is an 'iderteca' and how do you spell it?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

At the start of the film Red Dragon, Anthony Hopkins describes Ed Norton as an '*iderteca*' which is a word used to describe someone who can empathise or connect with the thoughts of others.
I am unable to find the correct spelling of the word, and the definition - can someone help?

Comment: [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Red_Dragon_(film)) gives the spelling as *eideteker*, but it does not appear to be a dictionary word. In any case, [*eidetic*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=eidetic+meaning) has a different meaning to what is supposed.

Comment: Eideteker is one variant. See  Yahoo https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100315121404AAjv1Us

Comment: I think the usual spelling is "eidet***i***ker". There was a question about this word earlier: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268526/where-does-the-suffix-ker-come-from

Comment: No corroboration that this candidate has been accepted into the lexicon is offered.

Answer (score 4):

> "Thus an eidetiker is able to see and spell correctly a wording appearing on a shop sign in [a] picture which he was shown even though he is unfamiliar with the language in which it was written. He is also capable of enumerating minor details of the picture even though these add little to its total significance. In short he behaves...as if the picture [which was removed] was still in front of him."

Distortion in Art: the eye and the mind, J.B.Deregowski (RKP 1984) p.45