# Is there a word for a kinetic ability magic user like how '-mancy' magic users have '-mancer'?

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a good noun to describe a character who can use Comakinesis, which is hair manipulation, but "Comakinesis-user" isn't good enough. Also, I can't find a word to describe hair manipulation in a magic user word ending in 'mancer' so I'm wondering if kinetic ability names have any kind of word form like that?

Comment: The use of '-mancy' (often '-omancy') is to denote fortune-telling (from the Greek _manteia_, meaning divination).

Comment: The fantasy series [*Keeper of the Lost Cities*](https://lost-cities-keeper.fandom.com/wiki/Abilities) uses plain-old _-kinetic_ as a noun, as in _a pyrokinetic_.

Comment: For a general term to denote such magic as does not merely read signs of what is to come or is otherwise obscure, like the various *-mancies,* but instead and more actively brings about seemingly impossible things, I suggest *[thaumaturgy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thaumaturgy),* Greek for" wonder-working," with associated agent noun *thaumaturge.*

Comment: You might be better asking in the F&SF, worldbuilding, or RPG groups on SE if you don't get an answer you like here.

Comment: Whoever made up that term sure butchered the meaning of the word coma. A comakinetic can be used. There are other examples in English of an ic adjective being applied to a person but I just can't think of an example right now.

Comment: @Lambie: "comakinesis" is presumably derived from Ancient Greek κόμη "hair". It's a distinct root from κῶμα "coma".

Comment: comi is not coma.

Answer (score 4):

### *-kineticist*

For the more common power *telekinesis*, the OED offers the noun [telekineticist](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/telekineticist_n?tab=factsheet#9919117832): "A person who practises or has the power of telekinesis".

Comment: That definition is behind a pay wall and telekinesis is about manipulating things, not parts of one's own body.

Comment: @Lambie You misunderstand — I'm not suggesting OP use the word *telekineticist*. Instead, I'm using it as an example of a word with that suffix which has the meaning the OP wants.

Comment: What's the point if it doesn't work for hair?

Comment: @Lambie Why would "comakineticist" not work for hair?

Answer (score 1):

### Comakinetician, Comakinetiker, Comakinetic

Some alternatives formations to *-kineticist* (suggested in Laurel's answer) would be *-kinetician* and *-kinetiker* (or *-kineticker*). I wrote an answer about the origins of these in a prior question, [Where does the suffix "-ker" come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268526/) *-iker* is a German ending that has seen some limited use in English, as in the case of the word *[eidetiker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eidetiker).*

You could also simply use "-kinetic" as a noun. For comparison, [telekinetic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/telekinetic) is sometimes used as a noun:

> "While Jean Grey is both a telepath and a **telekinetic**, she is only an Omega level telepath."

(Jonathan Hickman, quoted in "[X-Men: How Do Jean Grey’s Powers REALLY Work?](https://screenrant.com/xmen-jean-grey-powers-psychic)", Thomas Bacon, 2020 April 13, ScreenRant)